# Android List storing elements at incorrect indexes

Tags: android, arrays, list, arraylist

I am storing the selected item of the spinner, in an array "selectedPayment[]" which is storing lots of null values as well, so I've converted that array into a List "payMode". The problem is when i store the elements, the List is storing elements at wrong indexes. There is problem when I'm converting Array to List because an Array is storing items at correct indexes.

For example: I am getting [Cash, Paypal, Gift Card, Coupans] in a List which is not correct as I need to store elements in [Paypal, Coupans,Cash, Gift Card] order.

Please let me know where is the mistake.

Code:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
        long arg3) {


    if (parent == spinner_paymentOption) {
        selectedPayment[position] = paymentOptionList.get(position);
        System.out.println("=====selll "+selectedPayment[position]);
        payMode = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(selectedPayment));
        payMode.remove(0);
        payMode.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

        System.out.println("====paymode==="+payMode);

        if (!(spinner_paymentOption.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0)) {
            isTrue = true;
            if (items.contains(position)) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        mActivity,
                        "You have already selected "
                                + selectedPayment[position],
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                counter++;
                createDynamicPaymentLayout(position);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make payMode arraylist outside the listener as:

```
payMode = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and add the selected item as:

(You can put the below lines just after

```
selectedPayment[position] = paymentOptionList.get(position); )
payMode.add(paymentOptionList.get(position));
```

and remove this:

```
payMode = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(selectedPayment));
payMode.remove(0);
payMode.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

Comment: Its not working as well. It should be PayMode.add() and this is showing ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception..

Comment: Will the size of the arraylist payMode always be 4? You just want to rearrange in the order you have clicked?

Comment: No it is has no specific size..elements are added dynamically. I just want to add the selected item from spinner, in the List one after another not in a random order.

Comment: If the above code still doesn't solve, please post your whole code. Maybe I am not getting your question properly.

Comment: Thanks.. I've found the mistake.. :)